# How can remove white screen when page changes one to another page?

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have done my application in iphone using phonegap and jquery mobile. It is major project and it is totally completed. But there is one problem , in application pages load using rel="external" , when page changes one to another page in between  2 to 3 seconds screen display totaly white, that time don't want to display white screen. Anybody idea what can we do for that ? and don't reply with remove rel="external".

Comment: add some activity indicator to show your page is loading..

Comment: Hint : you ll have to make your native webview transparent

Comment: @Vicky: I have already changes done in webview color and style in native code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to make your native webview transparent then
Try giving css style to body as

```
body{
   background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: I have already used this one html, body { direction:ltr; background:url('../img/screen.png') no-repeat left top;background-size: 100% auto;background:#FAE7C3;}

Comment: then the problem is with your native webview's background color...its still visible..try to make it transparent..